# How do we add the truncated digit to the column values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example the column name is digits and it has values as

| Digits |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 234 |

The length of column digit should be 4 and the last digit truncated was 0.
I have to add the 0 to all the truncated values.
So that the column digit should have values as after adding 0 in the end.

| digits |
| --- |
| 1230 |
| 2340 |

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: ​Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tagging completely irrelevant technologies just wastes the time of the subject experts you attract that know nothing about the technology you are  *actually* asking about. Either way, tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about.

Comment: What type of column is Digits? varchar or int?

Comment: Multiply by 10, cast to int if necessary.

Comment: @Sandhya it is int

Comment: @Stu multiply by 10 won't solve my issue those were just random numbers. 0 is truncated from table values of a column that 0 has to be appended for all the truncated values

Comment: When will multiply by 10 not solve your issue? Add such values to the sample data.

Comment: @Ruhika can you show me a decimal number that when multiplied by 10 doesn't have a zero appended?

Comment: @jarlh i have the the digits 1230  for few values and for the few values when the data is ingested it has truncated the last value of the digits column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to append a random digit to all the values in column Digits, you could do :

```
UPDATE TblName SET Digits = CAST(CAST(Digits AS VARCHAR) + '0' AS INT)
```

And you can replace '0' with whatever digit you want to append?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: It didn't work and yet you accepted the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You say the length has to be 4, and the 0's to the right were trimmed. So add 4 0's to the right, and take the left 4 characters:

```
SELECT left(concat(cast(digits as varchar(10)), "0000"), 4) as digits
```